# Separating multiple digits numbers from numbers in Form1_KeyPress

Tags: c#, keypress

I am using a Keypress function to detect keypad-number-keypresses to use them later.

No bigger challenge in that.

Yet my goal is to also use 2 digits or more.

My approach

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (True)
    {
        string zahlj = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        DateTime dtj = DateTime.Now;
        if ((dtj - dtv).TotalMilliseconds < 500)
            zahl += zahlj;
        else
            zahl = zahlj;
        dtv = dtj;
        this.Text = zahl;
    }
}
DateTime dtv = DateTime.Now;
string zahl = "";
```

This works, assuming a delay of 500 Milliseconds between succeeding keystrokes.

The problem is that once the number was entered, a function B should be called. Now, how do I know that it's the final number?

Which is the right approach, when can I call B?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call B after resetting the `zahl` variable because every 500 ms there can be another key value. If not, you are already resetting the `zahl` variable with the current key value at else statement. So before resetting, you have the final number.

```
if (True)
{
    string zahlj = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    DateTime dtj = DateTime.Now;
    if ((dtj - dtv).TotalMilliseconds < 500){
        zahl += zahlj;
    }
    else {
        if(zahl.length > 1){ // if there is no other keypress after 500 millisecond, you have the result value at zahlj
           CallB(); // if length is > 1 so you have the result to call B function
        }
        zahl = zahlj;
    }
    dtv = dtj;
    this.Text = zahl;
}
```

Comment: The number can also be 1 digit, depending on whether there is a followup keypress within 500 ms or not. When it's 1 digit, B also has to be called.

Comment: So you don't need to check the length, just call B inside else.